# Not pushing new values to std::vector<std::unique_ptr<type>>

Tags: c++, arrays, qt, vector

I draw data columns as axes on the screen according to the data order. I also draw a matrix on another canvas. I can click and sort the columns in descending order on the matrix. Once I sorted the matrix, the new order is passed to the main canvas to redraw axes according to the new order. My problem is that the axes view is not updated even though I get new data order and values correctly. It seems m_axes.push_back() does not work. I also tried to sort data in reverse order without matrix, the view was updated. Thanks for the help in advance.

```
   Matrix::Matrix(QWidget *parent): QOpenGLWidget(parent) // Matrix.cpp
    {
       connect (this, SIGNAL(PassSortedOrder(std::vector<int> )),
                &canvas , SLOT(SetSortedOrder(std::vector<int> )));
    }
    
    void Matrix::SortMatrix(int clicked_row)  // Sort and get new order-Matrix.cpp
    {
        std::vector<int> idxs(naxes);
    
        for(int i =0; i<naxes;i++){
            idxs[i] = sorted[i].first;
        }
    
        m_idxs=idxs;
        PassSortedOrder(idxs);
    }
    
    void Canvas::SetSortedOrder(std::vector<int> idxs)  // Setting new order-Canvas.cpp
    {
        m_newAxesOrder = idxs;
        BuildAxesAndControllers();   
    }

    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Column>> m_data;  // canvas.cpp
    std::vector<int> m_newAxesOrder; // canvas.h
    
    void Canvas::BuildAxesAndControllers(){  //Build Axes Location and Values canvas.cpp
      
        m_axes.clear();
    
        if(m_newAxesOrder.empty()) 
       {
            std::vector<int> ordervector;
            for(int i = 0; i < (int) m_data.size(); i++) {
                ordervector.push_back(i);
            }
            m_newAxesOrder = ordervector;
        }
    
        for(int col_idx = 0; col_idx < (int) m_newAxesOrder.size(); ++col_idx)
        {
            int index = m_newAxesOrder[col_idx];
            m_axes.push_back(std::make_unique<Axis>(*m_data[index]) ));
    
        }
    }

  void Canvas::DrawAxes(int axis_color) // draw parallel axes- called in paintGL
  {
    for(auto& a : m_axes)
        a->draw(axis_color);
  }
```

Comment: I would think either `SetSortedOrder` or `BuildAxesAndControllers` should have something to trigger actual redrawing, instead of just changing member data. Does `DrawAxes` get called when you expect?

Comment: DrawAxes is called by PaintGL which means it is called all the time, before and after the change. Do you think the problem can be about pointing to old values in the vector?